# ResolvePackageNotFound error in anaconda enviroment.yml even when package requirements are satisfied?

Tags: python, conda

Am trying to follow the steps for [this (Sketch Recognition)](https://github.com/HPrinz/sketch-recognition). I have to run the command `conda env create -f anaconda/environment.yml`. I installed anaconda specifically for this command but I am getting this error

```
(base) [duke@void paper-implementation]$ conda env create -f anaconda/environment.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - freetype==2.8=h12048fb_1
  - readline==7.0=hc1231fa_4
  - pip==9.0.1=py35h33ce766_4
  - libffi==3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - python==3.5.4=he720263_23
  - wheel==0.30.0=py35h5c0b906_1
  - numpy==1.14.0=py35h8a80b8c_1
  - libedit==3.1=hb4e282d_0
  - sqlite==3.22.0=h3efe00b_0
  - hdf5==1.8.18=h017327d_1
  - openssl==1.0.2n=hdbc3d79_0
  - tbb==4.3_20141023=0
  - mkl==2018.0.1=hfbd8650_4
  - libgfortran==3.0.1=h93005f0_2
  - libcxxabi==4.0.1=hebd6815_0
  - ca-certificates==2017.08.26=ha1e5d58_0
  - pillow==5.0.0=py35hfcce615_0
  - scipy==1.0.0=py35h8b35106_0
  - tk==8.6.7=h35a86e2_3
  - jpeg==9b=he5867d9_2
  - xz==5.2.3=h0278029_2
  - zlib==1.2.11=hf3cbc9b_2
  - libcxx==4.0.1=h579ed51_0
  - intel-openmp==2018.0.0=h8158457_8
  - libtiff==4.0.9=h0dac147_0
  - matplotlib==2.0.2=py35ha43f773_1
  - scikit-learn==0.19.1=py35h2b554eb_0
  - ncurses==6.0=hd04f020_2

(base) [duke@void paper-implementation]$ pip3 install scikit-learn ncurses
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.20.2)
Collecting ncurses
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ncurses (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ncurses
(base) [duke@void paper-implementation]$ pip3 install scikit-learn 
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.20.2)
```

Am using Linux.

Comment: Also this might be a stupid question but why does it say that pip is a requirement? I had uninstalled it when I installed conda (someone had told me to use only one package manager system at a time). Reinstalled it to see what happens but it still throws that dependency error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently this is the reason:

> This problem can happen if the environment was exported on a different
>   platform than the target machine. For example, in the output above,
>   the environment.yaml has the package: pyyaml==3.12=py27ha7932d0_1, and
>   this is available only on osx-64, but the OP is trying to create the
>   environment on a linux machine, and it won't find the package in the
>   linux-64 subdir. There is nothing wrong in Conda here. Please explore
>   the --no-builds option to conda env export, which would relax the
>   constraint on the package build.

From [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7311).

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I am had this issue even if I created the `environment.yml` file with `--no-builds` option. The environment file was originally created on OS and I'm trying to re-create it on Ubuntu. I get `ResolvePackageNotFound: - libgfortran=5.0.0`

I had to manually delete the line from the .yml file and it worked. Not ideal.